# Calling a generic function in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I try to do a generic function of this

```
    networking.Ssl_Elts = (from line in allLines
                           let data = line.Split(',')
                           where line.Substring(0, Len("SSL_ELT,")) == "SSL_ELT,"
                           select new SSL_ELT(data)
                           ).ToList();

    networking.Ssl_Headers = (from line in allLines
                              let data = line.Split(',')
                              where line.Substring(0, Len("SSL_HEADER,")) == "SSL_HEADER,"
                              select new SSL_HEADER(data)
                              ).ToList();
```

By doing this :

```
public List<T>GetObjects<T> (IEnumerable<string> allLines,string ObjectName)
{
    var result =  (from line in allLines
            let data = line.Split(',')
            where line.Substring(0, Len("SSL_HEADER,")) == "SSL_HEADER,"
            select new T(data)).ToList();
    return (T)result;
}
```

So I would be able to call this function passing only :

```
networking.Ssl_Headers = GetObjects<Ssl_Headers>(allLines, "SSL_HEADER");
```

But it doesn't work.

Any idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what exactly does "not work" mean? Any exception? Unexpected behaviour? What is `Ssl_Headers`?

Comment: Btw. your method should return a **list** of `T`. However you cast the result-list to `T`. I suppose you can just omit the cast, as `result`already **is** a `List<T>`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere `select new T(data)` wouldn't work as `T` is not known to contain a constructor accepting `data`.

Comment: @GSerg That´s the most *obvious* one, but as you see in my comments there are many more including those we don´t even know as OP isn´t providing those information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic method: instantiate a generic type with an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327596/generic-method-instantiate-a-generic-type-with-an-argument)

Comment: `line.Substring(0, Len("SSL_HEADER,")) == "SSL_HEADER,"` is a [`String.StartsWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-5.0) Method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call `new T(data)`, because not every type has a constructor accepting a single argument of type `string[]`, however, you could use a factory function:

```
public List<T> GetObjects<T>(IEnumerable<string> allLines, string objectName,
    Func<string[], T> factory)
{
    objectName += ",";
    return (from line in allLines
        let data = line.Split(',')
        where line.Substring(0, Len(objectName)) == objectName
        select factory(data)).ToList();
}
```

Which can be called like this:

```
networking.Ssl_Headers = GetObjects(allLines, "SSL_HEADER", x => new Ssl_Headers(x));
```

---

And, as mentioned in the comments by @DragAndDrop, using `string.StartsWith` would be simpler:

```
public List<T> GetObjects<T>(IEnumerable<string> allLines, string objectName,
    Func<string[], T> factory)
{
    return (from line in allLines
        let data = line.Split(',')
        where line.StartsWith(objectName + ",")
        select factory(data)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't understand everything but it works

Comment: Basically, you can't call `new T(data)`, because `T` could be _any_ type.