# Generic function new with parameter problem

Tags: c#, .net, generics, new-operator

HI,
I have a generic function as shown below. It can be used to show a form by calling

`showForm(ch);`

IT works for the second function (new without parameter) ,But if I want to show form but with parameter in the constructor as in the third function (new with parameter) ,then I could not do it .Any one has an idea how to do it?

```
       void showForm<T>(T frm)  where T :Form, new()
        {
            if (frm == null)
            {
                frm = new T();
            }
            frm.MdiParent = this;
            frm.Show();
        }


        //Works for this
        public frmChild2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ChildToolStrip = toolStrip1;
           // toolStrip1.Visible = false;
        }

        //Does not Work for this
        public frmChild2(string title)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ChildToolStrip = toolStrip1;
            Text = title;
            // toolStrip1.Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show examples of how you are calling your showForm method?

Comment: @Matthew Here is how its called ==> showForm(frmObject);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using `Where T : new()` tells the compiler that `T` has a `public` no-arg constructor.

The second form does not have such a constructor.

From what you show, there is no real need to set the title in the constructor (how would the `showForm` method even know what to set?).

Since `T` is also constrained to be a `Form` you can set `frm.Text =` after instantiating the `Form`.

Comment: Thanks it solves specific problem.but just curious to know if we can pass the parameter to new()
may be some thing like  frm = new T("My Title");

Comment: You cannot set in the constraints that you want to have a constructor with a string parameter. The only way would be to call the constructor using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

`new()` guarantees that T will have a public constructor that takes no arguments - generally you use this constraint if you will need to create a new instance of the type. You can't directly pass anything to it.

Check this

[Passing arguments to C# generic new() of templated type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840261/c-generic-new-constructor-problem)