# Generic function which can return value and reference type objects

Tags: c#, generics

I've got a helper function to get values from XML which works fine with value types like ints and also strings. I also have some classes which take an XPathNavigator as a parameter in their constructors and I'd like to do something like the following:

```
    public static void SelectSingleNodeSafe<T>(XPathNavigator nav, string pos, out T ret, T def)
    {
        XPathNavigator node = nav.SelectSingleNode(pos);
        if (node != null)
            if (typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(XMLConstructible))
                ret = new T(node);// this won't compile
            else
                ret = (T)node.ValueAs(typeof(T));//this works for my use cases
        else
            ret = def;
    }
```

There is a will but is there a way?

Comment: The problem is that `new T(node)` is impossible. Generic functions can only invoke default constructors of parameterized types.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Generic new() constructor problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840261/c-generic-new-constructor-problem)

Comment: @chibacity : value types like ints.... and also strings

Comment: @Patrick I see, not easy to see that meaning when reading the question.

Comment: Donnie: It does seem like a duplicate of this question, but its answers don't answer this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new T` has some compile time checks (obviously as you've run into), but your use of it is based on run-time information. Even though you know typeof(int).IsSubclassOf(XMLConstructible)) will never be true, the compiler doesn't, so the `new T` has to compile whether you go down that path or not. Instead of using `new T`, use reflection to create the instance. An easy way is to use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx)

```
   ret = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), node); // this _will_ compile
```

Comment: +1 Along with some unit tests, could make a good approach. Will have quite a performance overhead though, which may or may not matter.