# Return instance of generic type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, return-value

I wrote a generic class and want to crate its instance from a static method. The problem is that I can’t create generic instance of the object. I know that it sounds confusing and it is better to show the code.

```
public class Parameter<T> : IParameter<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
            return false;

        return (typeof(T) == typeof(String)) ||
               typeof(T) == typeof(bool) ||
               typeof(T) == typeof(int) ||
               typeof(T) == typeof(double);
    }

    public XElement ToXml()
    {
        if (!IsValid())
            throw new InvalidParameterException();

        var xElement = new XElement("Parameter", Value,
                                    new XAttribute("Type", typeof (T)),
                                    new XAttribute("Name", Name));
        return xElement;
    }

    public static Parameter<T> FromXml(XElement xElement)
    {
        var sType = xElement.Attributes()
                    .Where(attribute => attribute.Name == "Type")
                    .Single().Name.ToString();
        var name = xElement.Attributes()
                                .Where(attribute => attribute.Name == "Name")
                                .Single().Name.ToString();
        var sValue = xElement.Value;//need to use this
        var typeVar = Type.GetType(sType);// and this to create proper instance of Parameter<T>

        //I need somehow set T equal to typeVar here and Set
        return new Parameter<T>() {Name = name};//this is wrong. 
        //I need return either Parameter<int> or Paramter<double> or Parameter<string> or Parameter<bool> 
        //basing on typeVar
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this possible at all... but looks like it is trivial object design requirement. Any ideas? 
Thanks!

**UPD**: I'm using .NET 4.0. Does it make any difference? :)

**UPD2**: Looking at the problem now I see that this is a silly question. And it is impossible to return such "generic" objects.

Comment: It is completely impossible to set `T` from inside the method.  Think: How could you possibly call such a method?

Comment: var parameter = Parameter.FromXml(element); ? :)

Comment: ofcourse you can dive in the realm of dynamics but i wouldnt dive in that one to quickly ;)

Comment: that's exactly what my suggestion implements... ;)

Comment: @Lucero yes. You are right! :) Thank you. I think I can close the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a non-generic base class and inherit the generic class from it (they can have the same name and only differ by the generic type). On the non-generic base class, create generic instances in your static method (which returns the non-generic base class as result). You can then cast this to the generic type you expect.

```
public abstract class Parameter {
  public static Parameter FromXml(XElement xElement) {
    ...
  }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public abstract XElement ToXml();
}

public class Parameter<T>: Parameter {
  public T Value { get; set; }

  public override XElement ToXml() {
    ...
  }
}
```

There isn't really another way of doing this, since in your sample the type for `T` is specified before the static method runs.

Comment: Thank you! I thought about that. Are you sure that there is no other way, given that I'm using .NET 4.0?

Comment: Yes, because this would violate the contract, no matter which version you use: in your code the `Parameter<int>.FromXml()` *must* return a `Parameter<int>` since that's the declared return type for this method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: T is evaluated at compile time. The compiler does not have any chance to know, to which actual type your 'sType' will evaluate at runtime. Also, in the compiled assembly, no generics exist anymore. Therefore, in order to construct a type at runtime, based on condition which can only get evaluated at runtime, you will have to pesent the compiler a concrete type for compiling anyway. So somewhere you may decide your return type in an if .. else cascade like that:

```
if (sType is String)
   return new Parameter<String>()

else if (sType is double)
   return new Parameter<double>()
...
```

This may be placed inside a factory class or right near to the XElement class, I guess. 
In order to be able to return Parameter for example, you may use an interface (or a common base class, like in another answer), which may stand for all Parameter variants. This is the reason, why the method, which parses the Xml IMO is better placed outside of Parameter.

Also, since it seems, you are cert of 'deserializing' from XML, consider using some de-/serializer functionality ;)

Comment: "Also, in the compiled assembly, no generics exist anymore." - I think your are mixing up Java's erasures with .NET's (real) generics. In .NET, each generic type forms a distinct type for each combination of generic types used as type arguments. You can create those at runtime using the `MakeGenericType()` on the open generic `Type` (e.g. in this sample `typeof(Parameter<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string))` would yield the same type at runtime as `typeof(Parameter<string>)`).

Answer (score 0):

This does work for custom classes but it may not work for value types.  Take a look at [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840261/c-generic-new-constructor-problem) to see how this work for heap types.

Comment: How does that really relate to the question here?

Answer (score 0):

As Indicated by SLaks, this is impossible. Think of it this way,

```
Parameter<???> value = Parameter<???>.FromXml(...);
```

How will you ever resolve what the questionmarks should be when it depends on the content of the XmlElement?

You should use a common class which both captures Value as an object and exposes type information.