# how create a generic method that can initialize value variable to 0 or ref variable to new (not null)

Tags: c#, generics

I have something like this

```
V Func<V>()
{
  // do stuff
  V res = default(V);
 // more stuff
  return res;
}
```

The problem is that I want res to be either 0 or a new instance of V

I tried creating 2 methods

```
Func<V> where T: new()
Func<V> where T: struct
```

but surprisingly this is not allowed

My workaround is to have 2 functions

```
FuncNew<V> where T: new()
...
res = new V();
....
```

and

```
FuncDefault<V> where T: struct
...
res = default(V)
...
```

EDIT: Summarize answers

new(T) will new up a ref or value type; I did not realize that

Comment: What is to determine whether the return value is a new instance of `V` or 0?

Comment: You haven't even written a proper method declaration, and the constraint of `where T : new` is invalid. Even if it *were* valid, you can't overload methods by type constraints.

Comment: On your attempted solution, [constraints are not part of the signature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx).

Comment: @Jon Skeet, is it possible to do what I want

Comment: @Oded - if V is value type then 0, if V is ref type then new

Comment: @pm100: thecoop has already shown you that it's possible to do what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `new()` constraint:

```
private V Func<V>() where V : new()
{
  // do stuff
  V res = new V();
 // more stuff
  return res;
}
```

Value types will be initialized to all-zeros, and any reference types will be initialized using their no-args default constructor.

If the reference type doesn't have a no-args constructor it can't be used with this method, and you'll have to use other ways (there are plenty of solutions to this problem elsewhere on SO, eg [Passing arguments to C# generic new() of templated type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840261/c-generic-new-constructor-problem))

Comment: And note that for any struct (including `Nullable<T>`), `new T()` is equivalent to `default(T)`.

Comment: return V; is a little fishy :)

Comment: Indeed; I should have looked closer at his method :)

Comment: @pm100: yes it does, I've just tried it. Unless you want to do something other than return all-zeros for value types?

Comment: i cannot say new V if V is value type (like long)

Comment: @pm100: Yes you can. Try it: `long x = new long();`

Comment: grovel apologies - my bad. ty all

Answer (score 0):

So you want the result object to be integer zero, or a new instance of your generic type? That's not possible because the generic type parameter would only be valid for the integer type unless you specify `object` as the return type.

```
public object Func<T>()
     where T: new()
{
    if(something)
       return 0;

    return new T();
}
```

If you're trying to make a default initializer, you just need to new up the type. This should work for both integer and reference types.

```
public T Func<T>()
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
}
```

Comment: Generally, it's better to use `new T()` rather than `Activator.CreateInstance<T>` directly, as the C# compiler inserts some optimizations to make it very fast for value types.

Comment: Indeed. After looking at your implementation, `new()` is more concise.

Comment: the 'something' I would need  to test is whether V is ref or value type

Comment: `if(typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(ValueType)))` should do the trick.