# Generics in C# - how can I create an instance of a variable type with an argument?

Tags: c#, generics

I've got a generics class, where I want to instantiate an object with the generic type. I want to use an argument for the constructor of the type.

My code:

```
public class GenericClass<T> where T : Some_Base_Class, new()
{
    public static T SomeFunction(string s)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return new T(some_param);
    }
}
```

I get an error on the

```
new T(some_param)
```

> *'T': cannot provide arguments when creating an instance of a variable
>   type*

Any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840261/c-generic-new-constructor-problem/840299#840299) is the best workaround i've been able to find....

Comment: Are you going to do doing this frequently?  What version of C#?

Comment: Another way is to create a public property on `Some_Base_Class`, and then you can do the following: `new T() { SomeProperty = "value" }`

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Take a look at [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx). For instance:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { null, null });
```

Obviously replacing the `null`s with appropriate values expected by one of the constructors of the type.

If you receive a compiler error about `cannot convert object to type T`, then include `as T`:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), 
                  new object[] { null, null }) as T;
```

Comment: That's the correct way, right.

Comment: This will work well, although it's slow and not a good choice if you have to construct the same object type many times.

Comment: Note the `as T` in `var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { null, null }) as T;`

Comment: And this works only if T is not a value type. For example if you need to use it with SystemNumerics.Complex which is a struct, then cast to (T) instead of using 'as T'

Comment: I like neatness, so you can actually write it as this `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), options) as T` which will work too