# How to initiate T type object of Generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a Generic Proxy Class contains T type object That is also a class. i wants to create a object of T.

```
class Proxy<T>: IClient
{
    T _classObj;

    public Proxy() 
    {
        this._classObj = //create new instance of type T     
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: e.g. Proxy<int> sample = new Proxy<int>(5); // if T, say, is int

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: [Potential answer for you.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6410370/263681)

Comment: @Javad_Amiry i want like this _classObj = new _classObj(); _classobject.GetData(); That what i wants

Comment: And what is going wrong?

Comment: why negative to my question

Comment: @RahulKumar Your question is a bit ambiguous, i've updated it to be more clear. Do you agree with the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `T` is a class and it guarantees that it has a `new()` operator:

```
class Proxy<T> : IClient where T : class, new() {
    T _classObj;
    public Proxy() {
        this._classObj = new T();
    }
}
```

otherwise, or if `T` is a `struct`, so you can do:

```
class Proxy<T>: IClient where T : struct {
    T _classObj;
    public Proxy() {
        this._classObj = default(T); // which will be null for reference-types e.g. classes
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

For call a method on `T` there is some different situations. But, according to question and comments, I assume that `T` is a `class` and it has a `new()` operator. Also, it implements  the `IGetDataImplementer` which has a method named `GetData`. So we can:

```
interface IGetDataImplementer{
    object GetData();
}

class Proxy<T> : IClient where T : class, IGetDataImplementer, new() {
    T _classObj;
    public Proxy() {
        this._classObj = new T();
        var data = this._classObj.GetData();
    }
}
```

Comment: how to do this _classObj = new _classObj(); _classobject.GetData();

Answer (score 3):

You can either use the default value for that type (which will be `null` for reference types, or one of these for value types: [Default Values Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx))

```
_classObj = default(T);
```

Or apply the [`new()` generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx), that forces the type `T` to have the default parameterless constructor

```
class Proxy<T>: IClient where T: new()
{
    T _classObj;

    public Proxy() {
       _classObj = new T();
    }
}
```

Comment: how to do this _classObj = new _classObj(); _classobject.GetData();

Comment: @RahulKumar You can't do `new _classObj()` because `_classObj` is the name of a field, not the name of a type. You have to use `new T()` - that's what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks,but then how to call the Method's in T

Comment: @RahulKumar You can't, because you don't know what type `T` is. `T` might be an int, or a string - they don't have any `GetData` method.

Comment: @RahulKumar Which types do you expect `T` to be? Is there any restriction? Like, `T` can only be a class that implements `ISomeInterface`?

Comment: But My T is Type of Class "my own class that containing some methods" that implements IClient interface.

Comment: @RahulKumar Which class?

Comment: @dcastro let me modify the code in question

Comment: @RahulKumar I believe you should post another question. This question about "how to instantiate a generic type T" has already been resolved.

Comment: sure asking some other question.... i want to convert classes in Type T except RealClient class

Comment: Thanks, i post the another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224047/i-want-to-convert-all-my-classes-in-generic-classes-then-call-classes-methods please do some modification in question if requires