# I want to convert all my classes in Generic classes then call classes methods

Tags: c#, generics

I want to use generics to be able to use a `Proxy` with any kind of `RealClient`.

```
public interface IClient
{
    string GetData();
}

public class RealClient : IClient
{
    string Data;
    public RealClient()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Real Client: Initialized");
        Data = "success";
    }

    public string GetData()
    {
        return Data;
    }
}


public class Proxy : IClient
{
    RealClient _classobject = new RealClient();
    public Proxy()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ProxyClient: Initialized");
    }

    public string GetData()
    {
        return _classobject.GetData();
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        Console.WriteLine("Data from Proxy Client = {0}", proxy.GetData());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what the question is.

Comment: why negative.. i also post one question this is the secound part of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223136/how-to-initiate-t-type-object-of-generic-class/22223202#22223202

Comment: This is very ambiguous, but according to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223136/how-to-initiate-t-type-object-of-generic-class/22223202?noredirect=1#comment33743948_22223202), I assume you want to turn `Proxy` into `Proxy<T>` where `T` could be any class that derives from `RealClient`. Is that true?

Comment: @RahulKumar Since you did not link or mention the other question, I had no idea that it existed.

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because it's not clear.. to be honest, I don't even see the point of using generics here.

Comment: right dcastro please do modification and put the answer

Comment: dcastro you are right but i confused how to do this in generic as i asked before in previous question

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're trying to implement the [Proxy design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/proxy-pattern.html), and you want your proxy to work with any kind of `IClient`.

If so, you don't need generics for this. This is what you'd normally do to implement a proxy:

```
public class Proxy : IClient
{
    private readonly IClient _client;
    public Proxy(IClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
        Console.WriteLine("ProxyClient: Initialized");
    }

    public string GetData()
    {
        return _client.GetData();
    }
}
```

Keep it simple.

Comment: you are right but i want the in Generic , bcz the Realclient class are many around 10 so that's why i want it in generic.

Comment: This code already works with *any* `RealClient`. If you have `class ReallyRealClient : RealClient`, this will still work. There's no need for generics, from what you're telling us.

Comment: @RahulKumar If I'm misunderstanding you, please post some code that uses a `Proxy` *without* generics that shows us the problem you're having. The code doesn't have to compile, just show us what you're trying to do.