# Instantiate different datatypes with same arguments

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an m-to-n association between source and target formats. (right now, m=2 and n=5, with n growing faster than m).

I want to get an event, the input format being an `Item` or `DbDataReader`, and convert it into other types, which shall provide the required constructors:

```
public MyEvent(Item item)
public MyEvent(DbDataReader ddr)

public MyEventDetailed(Item item)
public MyEventDetailed(DbDataReader ddr)

public MyEventInfo(Item item)
public MyEventInfo(DbDataReader ddr)

public MyEventNotification(Item item)
public MyEventNotification(DbDataReader ddr)

public MyEventReminder(Item item)
public MyEventReminder(DbDataReader ddr)
```

Each constructors is to be used by exactly one of the two DataStores:

```
EwsDataStore : DataStoreBase
DbDataStore : DataStoreBase
```

which right now each implement the abstract `getEvent` method from the `DataStoreBase`:

```
abstract MyEventDetailed getEvent(string uniqueId);
```

Now I need all the other target formats as well, so I want to make them generic like this:

```
abstract T getEvent<T>(string uniqueId) where T : IEvent, new()
```

with a possible EwsDataStore implementation being

```
getEvent<T>(string uniqueId) where T : IEvent, new() // TODO: All affected models have to implement IEvent interface
{
    Item item;
    try {
        item = Item.Bind(service, new ItemId(uniqueId));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new ArgumentException("An item by that Id was not found in the data store", "uniqueId", e);
    }
    // return T.FromItem(item); // Needs static IEvent.FromItem method.
    return new T(item); // IEvent has to enforce constructor with parameter Item on all implementing classes
}
```

and for Sql:

```
getEvent<T>(string uniqueId) where T:IEvent, new() // TODO: All affected models have to implement IEvent interface
{
    SQL db = new SQL();
    db.AddParameter("@uniqueId", uniqueId)
    SqlDataReader sdr = db.ExecuteReader("SELECT * FROM datastore WHERE uniqueId = @uniqueId");
    if(!sdr.HasRows) throw new ArgumentException("An item by that Id was not found in the data store");
    sdr.Read();
    // return T.FromDdr(sdr); // Needs static IEvent.FromDdr method.
    return new T(sdr); // IEvent has to enforce constructor with parameter DataReader on all implementing classes
}
```

But neither a constructor with parameters, nor a static method would be allowed on the generic type, each throwing one of the following two error messages:

> The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item
>   'T': cannot provide arguments when creating an instance of a variable type

Searching for these error messages; I found that ["the instance method can simply (sic!) delegate to a static method"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259026/why-doesnt-c-sharp-allow-static-methods-to-implement-an-interface/259079#comment-6247736), or I can use [`Reflection`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3054835/1827295) or [`Activator`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6410370).

None of them seems sufficiently easy/straightforward to write, understand, use and maintain.

Is there a straightforward way to use inheritance and generics to create all the different types based on the type I provide, which can be understood/followed by other programmers even if they are not proficient in-depth in C# inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I think you are misunderstanding the `new` constraint. `new` means that the generic type `T` has a parameterless constructor `new T()` which seems to be the opposite of what you want.

Simply remove the `new` constraint and create the instance of `T` using the `Activator` class: [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
 return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), item);
```

Also, do note that you can not define static members in an interface nor can you inherit them. Therefore there is no way in the language to express a constraint on a generic type `T` that would allow you to call `T.MyStaticMethod()`.

Comment: This would mean that a missing constructor causes a runtime error, not a compile-time error. Is there a possibility to make that a compile-time error?

Comment: @Alexander No, there is no way to constaint `T` so that it has an accesible constructor, no matter what the signature is. `new` only enforces that `new T()` is a valid call.