# Create Generic object inside class

Tags: c#, generics

I am making a base class from which other classes can be derived.

```
public class BaseClass<T> where T
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        TClassObject = new T("SomeText"); // Error here
    }

    public T TClassObject { get; set; }
}
```

'T': cannot provide arguments when creating an instance of a variable type.

What I am missing here.

Comment: That works for no parameters constructor. My case is with a parameter,

Comment: Well, you don't read the post attentively enough. The post give you the exact procedure to resolve your problem.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't saw other answers. It worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MSDN:

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor.

So it needs to be parameterless. You may want to look at `Activator.CreateInstance`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx

Comment: I have parameters to my generic object. Will Activator work for this?

Comment: Yes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx. `Creates an instance of the specified type using the constructor that best matches the specified parameters.` Check it out.

Comment: What if I remove new()?

Comment: No problem, since you won't be calling new() anyway. Just be careful not to hurt your code readability and maintenance by using `Activator.CreateInstance`. You could also accept a Func<T> as a parameter for the BaseClass constructor, and write it like this: `BaseClass<Orange> orangeBase = new BaseClass<Orange>(()=> new Orange("tasty");`

Comment: var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), "SomeText"); Now this returns me object. How I cast this to T type?

Comment: `(T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T),"SomeText");`

Answer (score 2):

The `where T : new()` constraint states that `T` must have a *parameterless* constructor. Your code is calling into a constructor that takes a string parameter, and it isn't guaranteed that your `T` will have such a constructor.

It is not possible in C# to create a constraint on a specific constructor signature. If you need this functionality, you're better off using something like one of the answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840261/passing-arguments-to-c-sharp-generic-new-of-templated-type).