# How to pass a generic type list as parameter to a constructor of TableSource in xamarin-C#-ios?

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, generics, xamarin

I am using a subclass of UITableViewSource for populating the data in UITableView in xamarin ios . I want to pass a `List<T> someList` as a parameter to the constructor of the class. While searching i came across this [Passing arguments to C# generic new() of templated type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840261/passing-arguments-to-c-sharp-generic-new-of-templated-type) , but it doesn't help my cause. How can i achieve something like this

```
public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
{
     public TableSource(List<T> list) where T : new(){
     }


}
```

IS this doable at all ?

Answer (score 1):

that will allow you pass a generic list type to the constructor

```
public class TableSource<T> : UITableViewSource where T : new()
{
     public TableSource(List<T> list) 
     {

     }


    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```