# Class template with value in C#

Tags: c#

Is there any type of template that can be used like the statement below:

```
BitSet<10> bitSet;        //we can create bitset with n bits, here is 10
bool b = bitSet.get<3>(); //get value of bit 3rd.
```

And how can I define a class like this in C#?

Comment: There are  no templates in C#, but only generics. They are TOTALLY different from C++ templates. Complete different beast from another universe. They just happen to look quite similar (actually not).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a simple class, with a Constructor parameter (10) and then just call any method that recall any bit. Templates are for datatypes afaik. Anyway, look at [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840261/passing-arguments-to-c-sharp-generic-new-of-templated-type) to verify if thats what you are looking for (Constructor parameter with a template with a given type)

Answer (score 1):

c# code is :

```
bool[] array = new bool[]{true,false,false,true,false,false};
System.Collections.BitArray bitArray = new System.Collections.BitArray(array);
Console.WriteLine(bitArray[3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly like what you want but you can do that kind of stuff by using `Indexers`.

```
   class BitSet
   {
      private bool[] _bits;
      public BitSet(int length)
      {
        _bits = new bool[length];
      }

     public bool this[int index]
      {
          get
          {
              return _bits[index];
          }

          set
          {
              _bits[index] = value;
          }
      }
   }
```

To use that class

```
 BitSet bitset = new BitSet(10);
 bitset[0] = true;
 Console.WriteLine(bitset[0]);
```