# Allowing optional constructor parameters to `T` method?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this method that creates an instance of a class, measures the time it takes to load the class, and has the option to call a method. I'm currently trying to implement the option to pass parameters to the constructor of this method (IE `T`) but I'm a bit stuck, can anyone help?

```
public static T CreateInstanceOf<T>(Action<T> configure = null) where T : new()
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var result = new T();

    configure?.Invoke(result);

    stopwatch.Stop();

    Logger.Trace("Loaded " + result.GetType().Name + " [took " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms]");

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'd probably start with [typeof(T).GetConstructors()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e687hf0d(v=vs.110).aspx) so you can determine what each constructor's parameters and associated types are. Then you can use [Activator.CreateInstance()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx) to actually create the object.

Comment: There's no guaranteeing through templates (or interfaces) that any non-default constructors exist.  So you have to use reflection.  And your function should succeed (or fail very gracefully) as long as the default constructor exists.  The comment from @itsme86 is a more specific (and probably helpful) version of this advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing arguments to C# generic new() of templated type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840261/passing-arguments-to-c-sharp-generic-new-of-templated-type)

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier if you keep the work of creating class instances out of this method, since the purpose isn't really to create objects - you just want to time the constructors. You could write your method like this instead:

```
public T TimeCreationOf<T>(Func<T> creator, Action<T> configure = null)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var result = creator.Invoke();

    configure?.Invoke(result);

    stopwatch.Stop();

    Logger.Trace("Loaded " + result.GetType().Name + " [took " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms]");

    return result;
}
```

(Since you're just timing, do you need this method to return the instance of `T` that was created?)

Now what you pass into this method is a function that returns a `T`. And since what you want to time is the constructor, you can just pass in a function that calls the constructor and returns an instance of `T`.

This makes it much easier because you don't need the `new()` constraint - `T` could be any type with any sort of constructor. And you don't need to worry about how the "timing" method will call the constructors - the functions you're passing in do that for you:

```
TimeCreationOf(() => new ClassOne());
TimeCreationOf(() => new ClassTwo(5, "X"));
```

Because you're calling the constructors directly you know exactly which constructor you want to call and what to pass to it. If you tried to write a generic method that could create all sorts of objects it would be really difficult.

And if you still need to pass in another `Action<T>` that performs some additional configuration on the object (and you want to include that in the timing) you can do that as well.

```
TimeCreationOf(() => new ClassTwo(), c =>
{
    c.SomeProperty = "x";
    c.DoSomethingElse();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`T` is not a method - it's a generic type, that you have required have a parameterless constructor, which you are calling. Since there's not a syntax to specify that the type implement a specific constructor signature, you're left with two options:

1. Use reflection (e.g. `Activator.CreateInstance`) to pass parameters to the constructor and *hope* that whatever `T` is *at runtime* supports those parameters, or
2. Require that `T` implement some interface that you can use to initialize the object:

   ```
   public interface IInitializable
   {
       public void Init(...parameters...)
   }
   public static T CreateInstanceOf<T>(Action<T> configure = null) where T : new(), IInitializable
   {
         T = new T();
         T.Initialize(...parameters...);
         ...
   }
   ```