# Can we pass parameters in constructor to a generic expression?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to take the Exception messages from the db and throw my custom exceptions with a generic structure. My custom exceptions have a construct that takes 2 parameters, string message and parameter in the exception type. Is it possible to pass these parameters as `TException(message, Exception)`?

```
public static class ExceptionThrower<TException>
    where TException :  Exception, ICustomException, new()
{
    public static async Task<TException> ThrowException(ErrorCode errorCode, Exception exception)
    {
        using var ctx = new ExceptionContext();
        var message = await ctx.ExceptionMessages.Where(x => x.ErrorCode == (int)errorCode).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        return new TException();
    }
}
```

Custom exception code:

```
public class DbAddException : Exception, ICustomException
{
    public DbAddException() { }

    public DbAddException(string message) : base(message) { }

    public DbAddException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException) { }
}
```

If such a thing is not possible through this code example, how else can it be implemented?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing arguments to C# generic new() of templated type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840261/passing-arguments-to-c-sharp-generic-new-of-templated-type). I recommend to check not only accepted answer, but the other answers too,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible simply because the constructor for each of the provided exception types could differ and you have no way to add constraints for the constructor of the type.

Personally I wouldn't create all of this plumming to generate an exception. I would create 1 or more custom exception type(s) (or might even pick an existing one) and put in a really clear error message. In the end an exception needs to help you find the problem. Translating an error code to a message doesn't really help with that and I don't see the added value over that.

If you need to throw the same message on multiple places than I wonder if the message is really the same and if so; are you repeating yourself in the code?

Answer (score -1):

After editing the code in this way, it was the way I wanted.

```
public static class ExceptionThrower<TException>
    where TException : Exception, ICustomException, new()

{
    public static async Task<TException> ThrowException(ErrorCode errorCode,Exception exception)
    {
        using var ctx = new ExceptionContext();
        var errorMessage = await ctx.ExceptionMessages.Where(x => x.ErrorCode == (int)errorCode).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        return (TException)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TException), errorMessage!.ErrorMessage, exception)!;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code has a few caveats: 1. It could crash if the provided type doesn't implement the constructor and the compiler has no way to verify beforehand. 2. Reflection is performance wise not the best option.