# Instance of type generic

Tags: java, generics

The my question is this:

Why can not instantiate a generic type with new T () and instead with newInstance() of the class Class you can do?

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731452/create-instance-of-generic-type

Comment: And what if `T` doesn't have an appropriate constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use reflection (`newInstance()`), because at compile time the class whose constructor would need to be linked is unknown. So the compiler cannot generate the link.

Answer (score 7):

Due to *type erasure*: the generic type doesn't know at execution time what `T` is, so it can't call the right constructor.

See [Angelika Langer's FAQ entry on type erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Topic3) for (much) more information.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you're looking at this pattern (taken from an answer to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)):

```
private static class SomeContainer<E>
{
    E createContents(Class<E> clazz)
    {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Here, when we create a `SomeContainer`, we parametize the instance with a concrete class (like `String`). `createContents` will accept `String.class` only and `String.class.newInstance()` will create a new (empty) String.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type at compile time, use "new Whatever()". If you don't know the type at compile time but can get a Class object for it, use newInstance().

99% of the time I know the type and I use "new Whatever()".