# How to create Entity Framework ObjectContext?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, objectcontext

I have many DBs in one SQL server.
I placed connectionString as template(look at `Initial Catalog={0}`) into web.config.

`<add name="ent" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ent.csdl|res://*/ent.ssdl|res://*/ent.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=1.1.1.1;Initial Catalog={0};Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

I want to create the objectContext with correct connectionString. I thought to do the following, `CreatObjectContext<SiteEntities>('MySite')` but I get error `Unable to determine the provider name for connection of type 'System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection'`.

```
public T CreatObjectContext<T>(string dbName) where T : ObjectContext, new()
{          
       var conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ent"].ConnectionString;
       var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(conStr);
       entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
       // Build correct conString to the db
       entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = string.Format(entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString, dbName);

       var connection = new EntityConnection(entityBuilder.ConnectionString);                          
       var builder = new ContextBuilder<T>();

       return builder.Create(connection);           
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? How I can create the context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using EntityConnectionStringBuilder, you only need to store the sqlserver connection strings in your web.config. EntityConnectionStringBuilder can then convert those to EF4 connection strings.

Example web.config

```
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="db1" connectionString="data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=db1;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework" /> 
      <add name="db2" connectionString="data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=db2;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

And we can change your method to something like:

```
public ObjectContext CreatObjectContext(string dbName)
{          
       var conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[dbName].ConnectionString;
       var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

       entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
       entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = conStr;

       entityBuilder.MetaData = @"res://*/ent.csdl|res://*/ent.ssdl|res://*/ent.msl";

       return new ObjectContext(entityBuilder.ToString());          
}
```

Comment: Related question entity-framework-runtime-connection-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368897/entity-framework-runtime-connection-string

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to share a small class to create an entity framework connection using the entity class as type of T an SQL connection string and the `entityModel` meta data name.

```
    public static class EFConnection<T> where T : ObjectContext
    {
    public static T GetDatabase(string connectionString,string entityModelMetadataName)
    {

        var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = connectionString;
        entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/" + entityModelMetadataName + ".csdl|res://*/" + entityModelMetadataName + ".ssdl|res://*/" + entityModelMetadataName + ".msl";


    var _db=(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { entityBuilder.ToString()});
    return _db;

    }

}
```

use example:

```
    var _db = EFConnection<Model1Container>.GetDatabase(Settings.General.Default.DatabaseConnectionString, "Model1");
```

I did use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/731637/1832488) post also to put everything together: