# Entity Framework runtime connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'd like to supply the connection string for my database at runtime. I am using the Entity Framework. This is what I have so far

```
class MyClassDBContext:DbContext
{
  public MyClassDBContext(string str) : base(str)
  {
    this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = str;
  }
}
```

To use the above code, I tried

```
//create connection string
EntityConnectionStringBuilder myConn = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
myConn.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
myConn.ProviderConnectionString = "user id=xxxx;password=xxxx;server=localhost;database=xxxx;connection timeout=30";

//inject the connection string at runtime
MyClassDBContext a = new MyClassDBContext(myConn.ToString())
```

The above code gave me an error saying "Provider keyword not supported".
To attempt to debug this error, I tried the following

```
 MyClassDBContext a = new MyClassDBContext("metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=user id=xxxx;password=xxxx;server=localhost;database=xxxx;connection timeout=30")
```

Now, I got an error saying "metadata keyword not supported". So I changed my code to

```
MyClassDBContext a = new MyClassDBContext("provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=user id=xxxx;password=xxxx;server=localhost;database=xxxx;connection timeout=30")
```

Now I got an error saying "provider keyword not supported". So I again changed my code to

```
 MyClassDBContext a = new MyClassDBContext("user id=xxxx;password=xxxx;server=localhost;database=xxxx;connection timeout=30")
```

and now it works!. My question is : how do I specify the provider and metadata at runtime? It looks like only the connection string is being accepted. I am using Entity 4.3.1 from Nuget.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

edmx file based EF require the "Provider" and "Metadata" content.  Code-first based EF doesn't require this, requiring only the regular connection string.  You could use a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` (instead of `EntityConnectionStringBuilder`) to build this normal connection string if you'd like.  But as you've seen, you need only specify the actual connection details.  The Provider and Metadata aren't needed in EF 4.3.1's DbContext Code-first paradigm.

Comment: So what would I do if I needed to connect to Oracle or MySQL using code first?

Comment: The EF connection string has `Provider="System.Data.Entity"` and `ConnectionString="res://big.csdl|res://ball.ssdl|res://mud.msl; provider connection string=&quot;..."`.  Regular connection strings have `Provider="System.Data.Client"` (or Oracle or MySql) and `ConnectionString="details to connect to it"`.  These two parameters are typically in an app.config or web.config, but you're choosing to craft them dynamically.  In EF Code First, you take the second path.  In EDMX land, you have to embed the second path's details in the first path's "Provider Connection String".  It is ugly.

Comment: it works with `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` (and not `SqlConnectionBuilder`)

Answer (score 10):

Building on [HatSoft's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11369087/35133):

```
var entityConnectionStringBuilder= new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
entityConnectionStringBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
entityConnectionStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = <your SQL Server connection string>;
entityConnectionStringBuilder.Metadata = "res://*";

MyClassDBContext a = new MyClassDBContext(entityConnectionStringBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I haven't had to use that DB yet, let us know what you find out   :-)

Comment: yes there is a string builder class - but i found it a little buggy and a bit of a nightmare for the noob - i ran with mysql in the end.

Answer (score 7):

The EntityConnectionStringBuilder class can be used to to specify provider and metadata at runtime

> e.g.
>
> var entityConnectionStringBuilder=  new
>   EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
>   entityConnectionStringBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
>   entityConnectionStringBuilder.Metadata  =
>   "res://*/Example.csdl|res://*/Example.ssdl|res://*/Example.msl";

Please see for more on [CSDL, SSDL & MSDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399604.aspx) in Metadata

Comment: yes, that is what I tried and it did not work. The code gives me "provider keyword not supported or metadata keyword not supported" error. Please see original post for details

Comment: Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient" shouldn't this be Provider = "System.Data.EntityClient"

Comment: That may be true but changing the provider does not help right now because I am getting the same error saying that the "provider" keyword is not supported.

Answer (score 4):

I followed this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-2-connections-and-models.aspx)

and also this one

How to use EF Code-First without an app.conf file?

Basically what I do is almost like you, create a constructor with a string and calling the base.

But I also set the provider in this constructor.

here's a example

```
public Context(string ConnectionString) : base(ConnectionString) { 
    Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client"); 
}
```

That way you can specify the provider. And you won't get the provider keyword error since you don't need to specify in the connection string

Here's how I call it.

```
var dbCont = new ClassLibrary1.Models.Context("DATA SOURCE=xxx;PASSWORD=xxx;USER ID=xxx");
```

Hope that helps took me long time to find it

Answer (score 2):

It's old question but maybe it will be useful for someone

```
 var provider = (DbProviderFactory)System.Data.Entity.DbConfiguration
            .DependencyResolver
            .GetService(typeof(DbProviderFactory), "invariant provider name");

        var conn = provider.CreateConnection();
        //conn.ConnectionString = "sample connection string";

        DbInterception.Dispatch.Connection.SetConnectionString(conn, new DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext<string>()
            .WithValue("sample connection string"));

return new SampleDbContext(conn,true);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! The problem I was facing was that I am not using a CSDL, SSDL or MSDL in my code, so I had nothing to set the Metadata property to (couldn't put in "res://*" either). By following your suggestion I was able to overcome this limitation. Much appreciated!