# entity framework connection string in the code

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I'm working on a winforms application that uses the entity framework.
I'm looking for a way to set the connection string in the code without using the app.config
Any help please?

Comment: You can pass it as a constructor to your context.

Comment: You mean you'd rather hard code the connection string in your application code instead of having it centralised? in a configuration file which would allow you to change the connection string without having to recompile and deploy the project if theres a change in the conn string.

Comment: [use this ctor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: yes, i don't want to use a configuration file

Comment: If you search google and this website, you should find plenty of examples. I have found many. Where are you getting stuck? Are you not finding something for the version of EF you are using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework runtime connection string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368897/entity-framework-runtime-connection-string)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=entity+framework+connection+string+runtime or http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=entity+framework+connection+string+runtime and see how far it gets you.

Answer (score 4):

```
void Main()
{
    var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;"
        + "Integrated Security=SSPI;");
    var context = new MyContext(conn);
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbConnection connection) : base(connection, true)
    {
    }
}
```

Does it helps?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as

```
public static myDBEntities getDBContext(String connectionString) {   

    myDBEntities DB = new myDBEntities();

    DB.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    return DB;
}
```