# One EDM, but allow user to select database

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, datasource

Edit: this is for EFv4

I am trying to use an Entity Data Model, but allow the user to select the database.  We have three tables which have the same data types and relationships between different databases.  Two tables which are linked many-to-many by a cross-reference table.  I want to create a simple program in C# that allows the user to view and edit the data, and the user must be able to select from different databases which have those tables.

I have created an EDM with the wizard based on one of these databases, but it's tied directly to that database, and for the life of me, I don't see a way to programmatically change it.  There is an option to pass a connection string to the entity object's constructor, but it just hangs when I do.  Every search I've tried has only brought answers to how to change the data source that gets built into the software, rather than setting it based on user choice.

Even if I keep hacking and manage to make this work, I feel that it is clearly not the way it was designed to work, or I would have found the answer in the few hours of searching and hacking I've already tried.  Can someone steer me in the right direction?  Basically, I want to bind my form controls to some code that represents the rules of the schema, and my understanding was that EF is the forward-looking way to do that.  I just don't get why it wouldn't be an option to allow the user to select the data source.

Comment: Version 4.0.0.0 - file version 4.0.30319.17929

Comment: I don't know if you'll be able to do this. There is metadata associated with the model and I don't think you'll be able to just switch databases on the fly using the EDMX approach.  If you go Code First, you should be able to do this without issue.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368897/entity-framework-runtime-connection-string) thread.