# What's with instantiating from a type parameter T not allowing constructor aguments?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, instantiation

If I have classes:

```
class Useless
{
    private string _message ;
    public Useless(string message)
    {
        _message = message;
    }
}

class UselessFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    public Useless CreateUseless(string msg)
    {
        return new T(msg);
    }
}
```

Why can't I instantiate T with parameters, like I could do with the following?

```
return (Useless)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), msg);
```

Comment: I find your `Useless` class hilarious, to tell the least ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure new() means that is must have a parameterless ctor (constrained ctor anti-pattern)

Comment: I added a a parameterless ctor and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply not supported at this moment.

There are work arounds:

- Mark the type T with an interface or class (where T: MyClass) and set properties or call its methods to initialize the instance.
- Your Activator.Activate (a slow dynamic method).
- The fastest dynamic method is to once use reflection to find the correct ConstructorInfo and convert this into a strongly typed delegate (in your case: `Func<string, T>`). You can call this delegate which will construct an instance with the given parameter.

Comment: Accepted for the `ConstructorInfo` option. I never knew this class existed, or, obviously, this application of it.

Comment: Many developers do not know about it. If you need any help with it, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor.

From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

**Possible workaround (not the same thing)**

If you make `Message` a public and mutable property you can do:

```
class UselessFactory<T> where T : UselessBase, new()
{
    public T CreateUseless(string msg)
    {
        return new T() { Message = msg };
    }
}
```

Comment: This would not work, Message is not a know property of variable Type `T`

Comment: Tried it, it works. Note that I added a constraint to `T : UselessBase, new()` but I agree the example is not very good and probably not what OP wants. I also made message a public property.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { msg });
```

I got it from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/731637/1522991

Comment: Um, that's basically what I said I was doing in my question, but with one small correction, thanks.