# C# - Returning an implementation when generic method type is an Interface

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns

This is how I want to use it:

```
var fooStuff = _foo.DoBarStuff().GetFooStuff(id);
```

I'd like to return the implementation when DoBarStuff() is called so that I can call GetFooStuff(id) to get fooStuff.

```
public interface IFoo() : IBar
{
    FooStuff GetFooStuff(int id);
}

public class Foo
{
    public FooStuff GetFooStuff(int id)
    {
        // get fooStuff
        return fooStuff;
    }     
}

public interface IBar
{
      T DoBarStuff<T>();
}

public class Bar
{
    public T DoBarStuff<T>()
    {
        // do bar stuff
        return T; 
    }
}
```

The T is any interface and when 'return T;' is executed I need it's implementation returned. As it is now, I get this error under T on 'return T;' line.

> T is a type, which is not valid in the given context.  Type parameter
>   name is not valid at this point.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: you must return an instance of T, not the type T itself...

Comment: `T` is a type. `return T;` is similar to writing `return int;`. Return *what* int? If your method created a `T`-typed object, return it. If you didn't intend to return anything, don't use a return value in the definition, use `void`.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731452/create-instance-of-generic-type#answer-731637

Comment: But I'm not sure how I can return the 'what'.. which in this case would be Foo.

Comment: How is `IBar.DoBarStuff<T>` supposed to work? It claims to return an instance of any arbitrary type `T`.

Comment: I think you're trying to do things too *dynamically*, you should create a concrete implementation of `IBar` that deals with the different creations of what T could be. This is the factory pattern. Otherwise if you keep trying to do what you're doing, you basically writing DI in a weird way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
public interface IBar
{
    T DoBarStuff<T>() where T : class, new();
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    public T DoBarStuff<T>() where T : class, new()
    {
        // do bar stuff
        return new T(); 
    }
}
```

But you will have to specify the type when using the method `DoBarStuff`:

**Usage:** `var fooStuff = _foo.DoBarStuff<FooWhatEver>().GetFooStuff(id)`

---

If you don't want to, make your class/interface generics:

```
public interface IBar<T> where T : class, new()
{
    T DoBarStuff<T>();
}

public class Bar<T> : IBar<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public T DoBarStuff()
    {
        // do bar stuff
        return new T(); 
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
IBar bar = new Bar<FooWhatEver>();
var fooStuff = _foo.DoBarStuff().GetFooStuff(id);
```

---

But all of this doesn't work for interface, only instantiable classes (with a default constructor).

For interfaces, you will need something to make the conversion between them and theirs implementations.

The simple way is to use a dictionary (for the testing purpose, but you can use dependency injection framework as @N_tro_P suggested, even if choosing between one of them, now, shouldn't be your main goal).

You will end up with something like this (don't forget your inheritance and the generic part):

```
public class Bar // <T> or not depending on your choice
// You can add this constraint to avoid value types (as int):
//   where T : class
{
    Dictionary<Type, Type> _container = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
    {
        {typeof(IFoo), typeof(Foo)}
    };

    public T DoBarStuff() // <T> or not depending on your choice
    // You can add this constraint to avoid value types (as int):
    //   where T : class
    {
        // get fooStuff

        return Activator.CreateInstance(_container[typeof(T)]);
        // You will get an error if T is not in the container
        // or if _container[typeof(T)] is not instantiable
        // or doesn't have a default constructor.
    }
}
```

The only problem is, you will have to fill the dictionary/container with all your interfaces/classes you want to use, it can become pretty annoying to deal with.
You might want prefer to use one of my first solutions instead.

Comment: What if I want T to be any interface and not just IFoo?

Comment: My bad, just delete IFoo in the constraint

Comment: Did you literally just edit your post to copy what I said reworded? Previously you said this can't be done, now suddenly it can with what I posted reformatted. Thief

Comment: @N_tro_P: according to the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38998949/revisions), I would say these edits happened prior to your answer (perhaps I am mistaken).

Comment: I was editing during he wrote his answer. I just figured out myself, I said something wrong. Like I'm still editing, since I figured out also the OP, want to use interfaces not classes.

Comment: @Groo according to the timing history no. He clearly saw my original post and then edited. You are looking at my edits (time) which were mostly gramatical. He stole my post and reformatted.

Comment: @N_tro_P If i get inspired by someone's answer, I quote him. If my answer is the same I delete it. I have some respect, you know.

Comment: @romain-aga so it's a pure coincidence that your original post said "it can't be done" which was then edited to say "This should work" with basically what I told him to do right when I posted? Then each subsequent edit was formatted with more and more of mine.... Sure. You even added Usage bolded. Nice touch. You are clearly a thief though.

Comment: @N_tro_P yes it is. I didn't read your post when I was editing, I just read before talking the dependency injection part. Because when I finished my edit your post was just in front of my eyes, not before. And as you can see, I quoted you for the dependency injection part.

Comment: when I do this `_foo.DoBarStuff<IFooWhatEver>().GetFooStuff(id)` I get this error IFooWhatEver must be non-abstract type with public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter T in generic type or metthod DoBarStuff<T>()

Comment: It's why i add an other part in my answer, because as I explained, you have to pass a class that it can be instantiate. You can't pass interface without explaining to your program how to instantiate it. If you used the container for your test, just remove the generic constraint, and that should be ok. (Also, I will edit my type names, because that can be confusing)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but not how you wrote your calling signature.

You never had your Bar not use IBar and Foo use it as an interface. So you *should* change that. You may be confusing how to interact with interfaces.

**Adjusted Code**

```
public interface IFoo
{
    FooStuff GetFooStuff(int id);
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public FooStuff GetFooStuff(int id)
    {
        // get fooStuff
        return fooStuff;
    }     
}

public interface IBar
{
      T DoBarStuff<T>();
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    public T DoBarStuff<T>()
    {
        // do bar stuff
        return container[typeof(T)]; 
    }
}
```

The usage of what you are asking is to ensure you put the type in then, such as this.

```
var fooStuff = _foo.DoBarStuff<BarStuff>().GetFooStuff(id);
```

This is how dependency containers work. They store with in it a Dictionary an instantiated object using the type as a key. i.e.
    Dictionary instances;

Then you can also have factories stored elsewhere, but that requires your signitures match or you just assume they have independent access to their dependencies, so you would have
    Dictionary> factories;

In general though, I would take a look at dependency containers. Whatever you are working on may simply be calling for it as a pattern and there are many already made so no need to roll your own. If you are wanting to return objects by type, that is a dependency container. 
Also, I would recommend injecting that through so you are not coupled to an container. In other words, wrap it in an interface and then use an off the shelf one (Unity, MEF, etc.)

```
public interface IDependencyContainer
{
    T Resolve<T>();
    void Register<T>(T instance);
    void Register<T>(Func<T> instance);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should remove OP's code from your answer, it is redundant (and won't even compile). Second part of the answer is helpful.

Comment: I still see `return T;` which is where OP was getting the compile error. This is the part which is fixed in the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38998949/69809).

Comment: @Groo - OK I see what you mean. I changed it to reference a container as it should be.