# Is it possible to pass a parameter to generic object constructor during instantiation of a generic object type in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

For Instance, I created a sub routine defined as follows:

```
Private Sub PCboPl(pList As List(Of Object), dt As DataTable)

    pList = New List(Of Object)
    dt = oDB.GSD()
    For Each dr In dt.Rows
        pList.Add(New Object(dr))
    Next

    pList = pList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.dName).ToList()
    cboP.ItemsSource = pList 
End Sub
```

The following causes a Too many arguements to 'Public Overloads Sub New()' error message

```
pList.Add(New Object(dr))
```

I suspect this is because I am trying to pass a parameter to a constructor that doesn't exist.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: dr is already an object... simply pList.Add(dr)

Comment: @Trevor you should use that as an answer instead of a comment

Comment: I would @Matt.. but I'm really not sure that is what he is asking....

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#. Please only choose relevant tags in the future.

Comment: @Trevor That wouldn't work because dr is used by the object that I plan on passing accepts dr as a parameter in its constructor.

Comment: Then create a new class instead with a constructor that required Dr as a parameter e.g. pList.Add(New YourClassName(dr))

Comment: @itsme86 C# and VB both are both in the .Net framework.. There are many times where I find C# solutions and then convert them to VB using http://converter.telerik.com/ .... and vice versa.... So therefore it does relate to C#... for my purpose anyway...

Comment: @Trevor I see what you're saying, but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of attempting to use a generic object?

Comment: @Trevor I may be confused. If I use your proposed solution, would I still be able to pass three separate objects to the function that require Dr to instantiate them?

Comment: THe constructor for your class can  have as many parameters are you like. But I'm now kind of lost as to where you want to take this.. your question really isn't very clear where your target is.

Comment: I am pretty sure you dont need to take the DataRows out of a DataTable, down cast them to Object  and store them in a new collection in order to use an ItemSource/DataSource even in WPF.  If you did, `pList = Dt.AsEnumberable().ToList()` is all you need

Comment: Thank you everyone for your efforts by the way!

@Trevor Essentially I am using WPF to populate a combobox, in which it is relying on two fields in the dataset, which is detected by SelectedValuePath and DisplayMemberPath

Comment: @Plutonix I essentially inherited this code and am trying to make it more efficient in a sense. There are "wrapper" classes that rely on Dr, in which the data in Dr populates the attributes in the class, which are then added to a list that serves as the datasource for the combobox. 

I like your idea, I am going to try it and see if it works

Comment: All you need is the DataTable.  No extra processing required.

Comment: @Plutonix that isn't going to work. The wrapper class that accepts dr in its                  constructor is necessary in my solution. I am afraid that there isn't an answer for what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks again.

Comment: @Plutonix I agree to a certain extent, the pList object contains logic that is necessary to the application. So the dr is required. Unless I rewrite the application

Comment: What constructor?  The Q just shows a common, ordinary (void) method.  The dr used there is a local loop iterator and is not able to be used elsewhere.

Comment: @oissac F# is a .Net language too. The tags are about what's associated with the question. Since this question is about VB.Net, it shouldn't have the C# tag. The reason is because this site serves society as a whole. Someone stumbling on this question when they're looking for C# material is a waste of their time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question ultimately was found in this link

[Create instance of generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731452/create-instance-of-generic-type)

I converted the code to VB.Net

Instead of using a generic object in my Sub Routine definition, I used a generic type and was able to instantiate a generic type, while passing a parameter to it's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, your `pList` has to be declared as a `List(Of Object)` per legacy code requeriments, but it actually is a list of another type (the "wrapper" class you mentioned in comments, but nowhere on the question) which receives a `DataRow` as a parameter in your constructor.

If that's the case, you just have to add a new instance of that `wrapper` class to your list.

```
pList.Add(New Wrapper(dr))
```

Now, be careful with this:

```
pList = pList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.dName).ToList()
```

`x` is object, and `Object` type doesn't have a `dName` property. Visual Basic allows you to do this kind of... "dirty" stuff, but for the sake of clarity you should at least `CType` your `x` variable to the `Wrapper` type.

```
pList = pList.OrderBy(Function(x) CType(x,Wrapper).dName).ToList()
```

Comment: I apologize for not spelling out all the specifics in the original post. I can see that I caused confusion. This is my first ever question asked on Stack Overflow, so please bare with me.

Comment: The caveat that I did not mention is that there are three possible wrapper classes, that utilizes the same Dr

Comment: Being a list of `Object`, `pList` can have instances of any class. You just have to do a type check every time you use its elements.