# Generic factory for concrete subclasses

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism, factory, covariance

Consider the following code:

```
public interface IEventHandler<in T> where T : IEvent
{
    void Execute(T @event);
}
```

For these handlers I implement some concrete handler-subclasses:

```
public class SomeEventHandler : IEventHandler<SomeEvent>
{
    public void Execute(SomeEvent @event) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Now I have a factory to retrieve the corresponding handler of an event:

```
public class EventHandlerFactory : IEventHandlerFactory
{
    public IEventHandler<T> Create<T>(T @event) where T : IEvent
    {
        // What to do in here?
    }
}
```

I tried to check the type of the event and then return the corresponding handler, but of course the type-system denies that:

```
if(@event is SomeEvent)
{
    return (IEventHandler<T>) new SomeEventHandler();
}
```

I wouldn't do this so hacky, but I wonder how to allow the code to make that interface with the `Create<T>` possible.

**EDIT**: When I loop through an enumarable of events the T is treated like IEvent so the type-system will throw an exception:

```
var events = IEnumarable<IEvent>() { /* ... */ };

foreach (var @event in events)
{
    var eventHandler = eventHandlerFactory.Create(@event);
}
```

The `Create(T @event)`-method will throw an exception because T is an IEvent and not the concrete type. I could solve it using `(dynamic) @event` but is not what I really want to do.

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create instance of generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731452/create-instance-of-generic-type)

Comment: What creates this - `events = IEnumarable<IEvent>()` - what's in the commented out code? Where do the `IEvent`s come from

Answer (score 1):

Classic factory pattern.
What I like to do for things like this is the following:

```
public class EventHandlerFactory : IEventHandlerFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> _eventHandlers = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

    public EventHandlerFactory()
    {
        //add a mapping between the type, and the handler
        //note - this could be done with reflection to automate this
        _eventHandlers.Add(typeof(SomeEvent), typeof(SomeEventHandler));
    }

    public IEventHandler<T> Create<T>(T @event) where T : IEvent
    {
        var handler = _eventHandlers[typeof(T)];

        if (handler != null)
        {
            //now use Activator.CreateInstance to instantiate the type
            return (IEventHandler<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(handler);
        }

        throw new Exception("Handler not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is how I would do it, though perhaps with a few minor tweaks. For example, it may be better as a static class. Also consider throwing an exception rather than returning null.

Comment: Didn't make it explicitly static as I normally handle this via an ioc container - I make my instantiation of `IEventHandlerFactory` a single instance

Comment: Yeah, that's a great reason to keep it non-static.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I face another (maybe related) problem with this. I loop through an IEnumerable<IEvent> to get the corresponding handlers from the factory; and because I do this the T is always IEvent and not the concrete type SomeEvent so an InvalidCastException will be thrown because these types don't match.

Comment: Not sure I understand.. Can you edit your question to show that code please?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

If you want to avoid reflection or your IEventHandler implementations do not have default constructors:

```
public interface IEventHandler
{
}

public interface IEventHandler<in T> : IEventHandler where T : IEvent
{
    void Execute(T @event);
}

public class EventHandlerFactory
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<IEventHandler>> _eventHandlers = new Dictionary<Type, Func<IEventHandler>>
    {
        { typeof(SomeEvent), () => new SomeEventHandler() }
    };

    public IEventHandler<T> Create<T>(T @event) where T : IEvent
    {
        Func<IEventHandler> handler;
        if (_eventHandlers.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out handler))
        {
            return (IEventHandler<T>)handler();
        }

        throw new Exception("Handler not found");
    }
}
```