# Add Item to List T Generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics

i'm not sure even it's possible but here the problem i'm trying to add item to `List<T>` as follow

```
public static SelectList  ToSelectList<T>(List<T> addlist) where T : new ()
{
    addlist.Insert(0, new T { Id = -1, Name = "SELECT" });
    var list = new SelectList(addlist, "Id", "Name");
    return list;                
}
```

`new T { Id = -1, Name = "SELECT" }` throwing error is it possible to add item to `List<T>`?

Comment: How do you expect it to work? There are classes in this world which do not have `Id` and `Name` properties. What if `T` is `System.IO.Stream`, then what is it expected to do
?

Comment: Your code further constrains T in that it requires properties Id and Name.

Comment: those instance i pass do have Id and Name i'm not sure to use for all classes, so let's say i do have base class with those two properties

Comment: @GayanRanasinghe You can create an interface like `INamedEntity` with `Id` and `Name` properties and add `where T : INamedEntity, new()` constraint.

Comment: you should use polymorphism, i.e use constraint to base class where all classes with Id and Name inheriting that base class.

Comment: you should declare Interface type with Id and name of the T. that way only you should access the properties. and assign  the values

Comment: thanks  umasanka,  M.kazem Akhgary , Yeldar Kurmangaliyev,  StuartLC and this is for those who minus voted if i do have proper explanation i never post here for the help if you do not have solution it doesn't mean question should get minus vote. thanks

Comment: I upvoted to balance out whoever downvoted your question. I honestly don't know what the downvote is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, via the generic constraints, you have declared `T` as any object with a default constructor.

The compiler performs type checking at compile time, and T does not neccessarily have the properties `Id` or `Name`.

A solution is to

- Create an interface which does have `Id` and `Name`,
- Modify every compatible class so it implements this interface.
- Add another generic constraint to your function, requiring the type parameter to implement this interface.

A compiling example:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id {get; set; }
    string Name {get; set; }
}

class Widget : IEntity 
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }    

    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}

public static SelectList  ToSelectList<T>(List<T> addlist) where T : IEntity, new ()
{
    addlist.Insert(0, new T { Id = -1, Name = "SELECT" });
    var list = new SelectList(addlist, "Id", "Name");
    return list;

}

// In your code
List<Widget> widgetList = new List<Widget>();
ToSelectList(widgetList);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you do not know what `T` is and what properties it has. `new` is not enough as your generic constraint. All it specifies it:

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor

If you want to go and just instantiate an object of type `T` then see: [Create instance of generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/731452/6400526).

But what might be better is just to create an interface with those properties, specify that your function gets a list of that type and then just instantiate an object of that type:

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList(List<YourInterface> addlist)
{
    addlist.Insert(0, new YourDerived { Id = -1, Name = "SELECT" });
    var list = new SelectList(addlist, "Id", "Name");
    return list;    
}
```