# Invoke methods with different number of parameters

Tags: c#, reflection, invoke

I have the following situation and want to implement it as dynamically as possible. Maybe someone has an idea how to solve it.

I have a "main" method which will call methods from other classes by there name. These methods have different signatures. My main method is called with parameters but the other methods can have none, all or only a subset of the origin parameters. Is it possible to invoke the methods with one call and the correct parameters can be assigned?

Solutions I would see are the same signature for every method or an invoke case for every possible parameter combination. But both I don't like. It would be great if there will be something more dynamically.

```
class Foo {

  public void Start(string name, Type1 param1, Type2 param2, Type3 param3) {
    var method = // getting the method from Bar1, Bar2 or Bar3 by name with reflection

    // Problem is now how to invoke the method with the specified parameters
  }
}

class Bar1 {

  public void Method1(Type1 param1, Type2 param2) {
  }

  public void Method2() {
  }

  public void Method2(Type2 param2) {
  }
}

class Bar2 {

  public void Method3(Type1 param1, Type2 param2, Type3 param3) {
  }

  public void Method4() {
  }
}

class Bar3 {
  
  public void Method5(Type2 param2, Type3 param3) {
  }
}
```

Thanks for every hint. :)

**Edit**

In the best case I can do something like this.

```
method.Invoke(instance, /* all parameters but only the needed will be used */);
```

This could be a kind of dependency injection. But not sure if this is the right pattern here.

Comment: I think not really. In this case I also have to do a case for every possible combination of the parameters. But I don't think that it isn't so easy possible what I want to do and it seems that something like this would be the implementation at the end.

Comment: @mburm maybe the [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading) method could be useful? Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731452/create-instance-of-generic-type-whose-constructor-requires-a-parameter) topic could be the solution that you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you both for the hints. I think I have to do a check which parameters are used in the method before the invoke call. With that information I can create an array for the parameters and execute the invoke call.